# User Wallposts not showing up on Page

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I've searched high and low for an answer to this issue but haven't been able to figure it out. Basically, If I post as "User A" using a simple FB app I have on "Page B", the post made by that user (via the app) is only displayed to the user. If I log in to the page, or visit the page as a guest or different user, the post can't be seen.

Example:
http://screencast.com/t/gl1Ko0f35

Code I'm using:

post = FbGraph::Page.new(PAGE_ID, ACCESS_TOKEN)
post.feed!(:message => "This is my message")

This had been working previously but now the posts are only viewable by "User A". To make sure it wasn't the code itself, I left wallposts using Facebook as "User A". The post still is only viewable by the user. As the page, the settings allow anyone to post on that wall. It seems that after using the API to send messages, Facebook thinks that the user is spam...however, as the page I don't even see the notifications. It's as if the post never existed.

Has anyone else run into this? Any help would be great.

Cheers!

Comment: This could be because of either Privacy settings of the user or the post settings of the page.

Comment: @Vijay I did check the settings of both the poster and the page and they're set to accept wallposts and comments from anyone.